# Web-scraping for a specific class of tag

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to draw financial data from the Australian stock exchange (ASX). Specifically, the share registry for a particular company.

The website would be something like [this](https://www.asx.com.au/asx/share-price-research/company/BFG/details) (I say something because the ticker in the URL would change from firm to firm).

The HTML snippet I am looking at is:

```
<td class="ng-binding">COMPUTERSHARE INVESTOR SERVICES PTY LIMITED
                <br>Yarra Falls, 452 Johnston Street, ABBOTSFORD, VIC, AUSTRALIA, 3067</td>
```

My overarching goal is to create a spreadsheet whereby I would have a list of Ticker Symbols and a macro would take that symbol, place it in the url and draw the adjacent Share Registry value into Excel. (In this case, COMPUTERSHARE INVESTOR SERVICES PTY LIMITED)

I tried to figure out how to use a variable url (I believe it involves Concatenation) and draw financial tables from websites.
I've settled on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOzHacoP-u4&t=691s) tutorial that doesn't post the results into Excel, just presents it in a box. If I can results to post in the box that'll be a great first step.
Many tutorials use the IE object and from what I can gather, the use of XMLHttpRequest is far more efficient and nimble and considering I would have a large number of ticker symbols, would probably be best to use with regards to time.

```vb
Sub Get_Web_Data()
    ' TeachExcel.com
    
    Dim request As Object
    Dim response As String
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim website As String
    Dim price As Variant
    
    ' Website to go to.
    website = "https://www.asx.com.au/asx/share-price-research/company/BFG/details"
    
    ' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
    request.Open "GET", website, False
    
    ' Get fresh data.
    request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    
    ' Send the request for the webpage.
    request.send
    
    ' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
    response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    
    ' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
    html.body.innerHTML = response
    
    ' Get the price from the specified element on the page.
    price = html.getElementsByClassName("disclaimer disclaimer-company-info").Item(0).innerText
    
    ' Output the price into a message box.
    MsgBox price
    
End Sub
```

I edited the code to present the only HTML class element that seems to be working for me, which is the disclaimer info at the bottom of the page. I gather that the use of `html.getElementsByClassName` is wrong in my scenario.

I have read that CSS Selectors might be applicable in this case and the use of 'children' (I think) as the info I am after (ng-binding) occurs numerous times throughout the table, so I gather I would need to direct the macro to select the nth instance.

I do not expect a completely written extract. Any hints and tips to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Good answer from ASH. I want support you in two questions. **1**: XMLHttpRequest is faster than the use of the IE, that's right. But every page with dynamic elements which need to load via JS, needs a web engine which can process JS. But XMLHttpRequest can't. So you need the IE or Selenium to get all data you want, if you work with VBA. **2**: You can't use `getElementsByClassName()`  with XMLHttpRequest, because XML doesn't know CSS classes. Same thing with the method `hasAttribute()`. XMLHttpRequest don't know it, because XML is wellformed. An Attribute is there or not in every case.

Comment: I would extend upon zwenn comment - you do not necessarily only need a web engine if you can find the required xhr requests dynamic pages make to update page content in source. You can look for these in the network tab of the browser. Additionally, some can be determined from html that is actually present in xhr initial response.

Comment: Are the prices only visible at specific times? For your class selector I see _Price data for 52 week low, 52 week low date, 52 week high, 52 week high date, Annual dividend yield, P/E and EPS provided by Thomson Reuters © Thomson Reuters Limited_ currently rather than a price. I can see price info on the **summary** page. Did you actually want that entire table shown above?

Comment: I just added a loop to iterate through different stock tickers listed in an array in ColumnA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Sub Web_Table_Option_Two()
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Navigate "https://www.asx.com.au/asx/share-price-research/company/BFG/details"

    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 And Not objIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) 'wait for java script to load
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objIE.Document.body.innerHTML
    With HTMLDoc.body
        Set objTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")
        For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
            For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
                For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
                Next lngCol
            Next lngRow
            ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
        Next lngTable
    End With
    objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

[image]

If you want to specify the row, you can do that, and just grab the row number that you want/need.

Finally, if you want to loop through an array of stock tickers, use the code below.

```
Sub Web_Table_Option_Two()
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Set sht = wb.Sheets("Stocks")

    'find last used row in ColumnA
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

    mystock = c.Value

        objIE.Navigate "https://www.asx.com.au/asx/share-price-research/company/" & mystock & "/details"

        Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 And Not objIE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = mystock

        ActRw = 1
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) 'wait for java script to load
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objIE.Document.body.innerHTML
        With HTMLDoc.body
            Set objTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")
            For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
                For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
                    For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
                    Next lngCol
                Next lngRow
                ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
            Next lngTable
        End With

    Next c

    objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, I have been all over this the past few weeks! This was an incredibly helpful post. At this point in time I am working on having the script present just the share registry value next to the ticker symbol. I have been successful in isolating the share registry value (woohoo!) and have been partially successful in removing the 'new sheet' part of your code and instead pasting the result into the Stocks sheet. I will continue my research and will post my results when it is all done and ready. Again, thank you!

Comment: Happy to help!!